# Error reading Entity Framework from service configuration

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I am using this guide : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/

I moved the Entity Framework connection string to Service configuration.

The connection string seems to be truncated right after initial catalog.

This is my code :

```
public class ContosoAdsContext : DbContext
{
    public ContosoAdsContext() 
        : base((new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ContosoAdsContext")).ToString()))
```

This is the error :

> Message=Keyword not supported: 'tcp:sqlserver-xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog'.
>   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Check what the string looks like. I believe it hasn't been truncated, its just showing exactly at which part in the string an error happens. Make sure you don't have any `&quot;` values, replace them with single apostrophe: `'`

Comment: It is possible that the connection string is truncated during the paste from clipboard into service configuration value field. Check manually your connection string is not truncated. Your connection string should look like this: `Server=tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={dbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={username};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;` There is any quotation mark inside. The type of settings should be String.

Answer (score 0):

i finally realized that the problem was an invalid SQL Connection string.

and the line should be this :

```
        public ContosoAdsContext() : base(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ContosoAdsContext"))
```